# Is there a way to retrieve the Azure DevOps picklist information through .NET client libraries?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using [.NET client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops) such as [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/) to retrieve the work items in Azure DevOps.

However, I could not find how to get the **picklist** information through the .NET client libraries though it is mentioned in the [Azure DevOps Services REST API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/lists/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) (See below image)

[image: Get picklist information using the Azure DevOps Services REST API]

Is there a way to retrieve the picklist information through the .NET client libraries (such as via Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client)?

Comment: Is the following api helpful for you?

Comment: For the moment I've used the REST API. Should use this Client Library sample code you have posted here and check whether it does what I need. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check the sample here: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/main/ClientLibrary/Samples/WorkItemTrackingProcess/ProcessesSample.cs

```
            string _personalAccessToken = "xxxxxx";
            VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential("", _personalAccessToken);
            var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(@"https://dev.azure.com/xxx"), credentials);

            WorkItemTrackingProcessHttpClient client = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingProcessHttpClient>();

            Console.Write("Getting list of processes....");

            List<ProcessInfo> list = client.GetListOfProcessesAsync().Result;

            if (list == null || list.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No processes found");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Done");

                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}    {1}    {2}", item.Name, item.TypeId, item.ReferenceName);
                }
            }
```